# Server Docker not found, Cannot connect to Docker daemon, Docker Machine executable is not specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, macos

I'm learning Java and Spring Boot with a tutorial and there is a docker-compose.yml which I should run, but I get an error:

> Error running 'docker-compose.yml: Compose Deployment': Server Docker not found

I opened Preferences and there really wasn't configured integration, so I tried to add one, but I got another error:

> Cannot connect: Cannot connect to Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Details: [2] No such file or directory)

In the Docker Tools I found the Docker Machine executable is not specified. But I have no clue what  there should be and Google isn't helping me.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? See also: [ask]. ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Have you in fact installed Docker (Docker Engine on native Linux, most likely Docker Desktop on MacOS or Windows)?  What's in the Compose file; can you run your application with just a JVM?

Comment: Sorry, IntellijIDEA. I thought the Docker plugin is enough.
Installed Docker, restarted IDEA and it's working. Thank you.